# Just how bad is it to determine when to stop data collection based on the resulting CI?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, confidence-interval, sequential-analysis

Say I want to be $95\%$ sure of the mean $\bar X$, with a CI of size $2$ ($1$ in each direction).

The following is bad practice:

collect data until $1.96\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}=1$.

What is the extent that this is a bad practice? To be more precise, let's call this algorithm the ''silly algorithm''. If I run a ''silly algorithm'' then *EXACTLY* how likely is the true mean to be in my CI? What is an analysis of this situation?

Comment: Are you checking every observation? Do you stop the first time the half-width is not greater than 1?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Of course that's bad form, but my question is how to quantify how imprecise the results are.

Comment: The error created by using a Z test instead of a t test is about an order of magnitude greater than the error induced by using an incorrect sequential procedure!